# <ProjectName.ProjectUI sucks as a name for my Netbeans java OS X app

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, menubar

What property in Netbeans to I need to change to set the name of my java swing app in the OS X menubar and dock? I found info.plist, but changing @PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIEER@ in multiple keys here had no effect.

Thanks,
hating netbeans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on how you run your application. If you run it from the command line, use '-Xdock:name=appname' in the JVM arguments. See the section "More tinkering with the menu bar" in the article linked to by Dan Dyer.

If you are making a bundled, double-clickable application, however, you just need to set the standard CFBundle-related keys in your application's Info.plist (see the [documentation on Info.plist keys](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/PListKeys.html) for more details).

Comment: extra points for command line solution! thanks ever so much -- and sorry for the slow response.

Answer (score 2):

Check:

```
nbproject/project.properties

nbproject/project.xml
```

in project.xml look for the name element...

But... Why not just select the main project and right click and do rename?

Answer (score 0):

This is not NetBeans-specific, but [this article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/JavaLP/JavaToMac/) has some useful tips about tweaking your Swing apps so that they fit in on OS X.